# How to replace the BinaryFormatter in UWP apps

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, uwp, binaryformatter

I'm trying to move a .net project into an UWP app and the old codebase is using the binaryformatter to read some very important files. Unfortunately the Binaryformatter is absent in the UWP apps (or am I wrong).

Does anyone know any good substitute for the BinaryFormatter that I can use?

Thx

Comment: The best way would probably be to use that old project to convert the files into a more future-proof format, such as XML (using DataContractSerializer) or JSON

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the UniversalSerializer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620154/UniversalSerializer or the MobileFormatter in CSLA.net